# How to fetch data from firebase firestore and store the data in useState hook

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am fetching all `docs` from firebase, I did it successfully, I can even log it in console.

Mapping through the list is the problem.

> The fetch API takes time before it returns the data, while my map function runs
> immediately after the components were invoke, at that moment the API didn't return
> anything, so map function will have nothing to map.

```
import { firebaseDB } from "./db";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const responseArr: any[] = [];

// GETS ALL AVAILABLE DOCS IN GOALs COLLECTION
const getAllGoals = async () => {
  const response = await getDocs(collection(firebaseDB, "goals"));
  response.forEach((doc) => {
    responseArr.push(doc.data());
  });
};

export { getAllGoals, responseArr };
```

Now all I want is to wait for response then store it array in in `useState()`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import OnprogressGoals from "./OnprogressGoals";
import GoalsDone from "./GoalsDone";
import { getAllGoals, responseArr } from "../../containers/GetAllGoals";

const GoalList = (props: any) => {
  const [refresh, setrefresh] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllGoals();
    responseArr.map((goal) => {
      const goaler: any = [...refresh, goal];
      setrefresh(goaler);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(refresh);

  const OnprogressGoalsResponse = responseArr.filter(
    (Goal) => Goal.GoalCompletion === "Onprogress"
  );

  const GoalsDoneResponse = responseArr.filter(
    (Goal) => Goal.GoalCompletion === "Done"
  );
  return (
    <div className="h-[85%] overflow-y-scroll scrollbar-thin scrollbar-thumb-gray-900 scrollbar-track-gray-50">
      <button onClick={() => alert("I am clicked")}>click me</button>
      <table className="w-full h-full">
        <>
          <tr className="border-b px-5">
            <td className="text-sm font-medium py-5 pl-5">
              <span>Date created</span>
            </td>
            <td className="text-sm font-medium py-5">
              <span className="border-l pl-3">Goal name</span>
            </td>
            <td className="text-sm font-medium py-5">
              <span className="border-l pl-3">Due date</span>
            </td>
            <td className="text-sm font-medium py-5 pr-5">
              <span className="border-l pl-3">Goal target</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colSpan={4} className="px-5">
              <h1 className="py-5 font-semibold text-2xl">On progress</h1>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {/* {console.log(`Goal List - ${props.goalsList}`)} */}
          <OnprogressGoals
            ShowGoalDetail={props.ShowGoalDetail}
            goalsList={OnprogressGoalsResponse}
          />
          <tr>
            <td colSpan={4} className="px-5">
              <h1 className="py-5 font-semibold text-2xl">Goal done</h1>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <GoalsDone
            ShowGoalDetail={props.ShowGoalDetail}
            goalsList={GoalsDoneResponse}
          />
        </>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GoalList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dependency array is empty that why useEffect is called only once after the render and  your component cannot render the update data in responeArr. So to call it when data is load put your *responseArr* as dependancy in the useEffect. Just update your useEffect with the below code

```
useEffect(() => {
    getAllGoals();
    responseArr&&responseArr.map((goal) => {
      const goaler: any = [...refresh, goal];
      setrefresh(goaler);
    });
  }, [responseArr]);
```

Comment: it works like magic, though I have already fixed the issue, i tried to be an adventurous, and applied you solution ,and it works thanks for taking your time to provide me with this solution.

Comment: It works fine in user point view. But need to sure function not loop again and again, I have no enough time to understand your code. but sure u need to check put console.log( ) in getAllGoals( ) how much time it call backend firebase

Answer (score 0):

That's right because the `responseArr` doesn't waiting for getAllGoals.
Try this:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        getDocs(collection(firebaseDB, "goals")).then((response) => {
            response.forEach((goal) => {
            const goaler: any = [...refresh, goal];
            setrefresh(goaler);
            }
        }
        );
      }, []);
```

Comment: One more think, you should use `forEach` instead of `map` if you doesn't need the new array

Comment: Using `useState` in a loop isn't that going to cause too many re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

remove responseArr and use responseArr as useState(), I hope that help you

```
// const responseArr = []; it not update your component after rendeing component

let ArrEmpWithType : Array<any> = []
const GoalList = (props: any) => {
    const [responseArr, setresponseArr] = useState(ArrEmpWithType);
    const [refresh, setrefresh] = useState([]);
    const getAllGoals = async () => {
        const response = await getDocs(collection(firebaseDB, "goals"));
        response.forEach((doc) => {
            let Mydoc: any = doc.Data();
            Mydoc.id = doc.id;
            setresponseArr([...responseArr, Mydoc]) 
        });

        
    };
   
    useEffect(() => {getAllGoals(); }, []);
    useEffect(() => { }, [responseArr]);// it help rerender after update responseArr
```

Comment: `it works like magic`, though I have already fixed the issue, I tried to be an adventurous, and applied you solution, Sometimes code works but you will have no idea why they work. `Mydoc.id = doc.id;` obviously